# Filtering records for all values of an array in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am very new to Spark.

I have a very basic question. I have an array of values:

```
listofECtokens: Array[String] = Array(EC-17A5206955089011B, EC-17A5206955089011A)
```

I want to filter an RDD for all of these token values. I tried the following way:

```
val ECtokens = for (token <- listofECtokens) rddAll.filter(line => line.contains(token))
```

Output:

```
ECtokens: Unit = ()
```

I got an empty Unit even when there are records with these tokens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is each RDD line?

Comment: Each line in RDD is a string like context_type=EC-Token&token=EC-17A5206955089011B

Comment: And what should ECtokens contain? All the lines with a valid token? or a counter of all the lines with a valid token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get that result in a more efficient way and the result would be a filtered RDD:

```
val filteredRDD = rddAll.filter(line => listofECtokens.exists(line.contains))
```

And then to get the result as an array you should call collect or take on the filteredRDD:

```
//collect brings the RDD to the driver so be carefull cause that can result in a OutOfMemory in that machine
val ECtokens = filteredRDD.collect()
//if you only need to print a few elements of the RDD, a safer approach is to use the take()
val ECtokens = filteredRDD.take(5)
```